# How do I make a server return an html file?

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, jersey

I don't know how to explain my issue very well. I don't have much experience in this regard, and tutorials on youtube don't really help.

I have an URI like this on my WebApp, OhSnip/user/profile/, which I can access through http://localhost:8080/OhSnip/user/profile/

And I have a button on my index.html called Profile, which makes a GET request to the server, and returns a JSON file.

But I don't want a JSON file, I want a "profile.html" file with the contents of the JSON file on it.

Let's say guy1 goes to reddit or something, he logs in and clicks his name to go to his profile, which is https://www.reddit.com/user/guy1/.
Then, guy2 also logs in and goes to his profile. https://www.reddit.com/user/guy2/.

The profiles of the 2 different people are obviously different, but the USER page they are displayed on is the exact same.

That's what I want, I want to display the information contained in the JSON files in a User page.

But I doubt having something like

```
window.location.href='profile.html';
```

on the client side is the way to do it.

Maybe it's a template system? I don't know even know anymore.

I think in Node.js, you could define a request(req) and a response(res) and then use something like res.render(), but I'm not so sure anymore. I remember using Jade and Handlebars for that, but I think it's different.

This is probably very straightforward, but it's driving me borderline mad.

Anyway, thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to build some front app on which you will receive the data of your server's call, and display and format it the way you want. You could use whatever JS framework you fill confortable with to achieve this.

Comment: you are asking how to create a website, its too broad

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node as your backend you can send a html file back as a reply for a specific path using express.js.

It would look something like this (assuming page.html is in the public folder):

```
app.get('/page', (req,res)=>{

        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/page.html'));
    });
```

Read more on their site: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html